# Which expression is equivalent to $\frac{\sqrt{3+x}}{\sqrt{3-x}}$ for all $x$ such that $-3 < x < 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Which expression is equivalent to $$\frac{\sqrt{3+x}}{\sqrt{3-x}}$$ for all $x$ such that $-3 < x < 3$?

This is a question in the ACT practice book.  The answer is $$\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3-x}$$

But why?  Why not just $$\frac{3+x}{3-x}$$?

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for tips on making your equations more readable.

Comment: Always good to try examples:  Suppose $x=1$.  Then the given expression is $\frac {\sqrt {4}}{\sqrt 2}$.  Is that equal to your expression?

Comment: Great tip - Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{3+x}}{\sqrt{3-x}} = \frac{\sqrt{3+x}\sqrt{3-x}}{\sqrt{3-x}\sqrt{3-x}}$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{(3+x)(3-x)}}{\left(\sqrt{3-x}\right)^2}$$

$$= \frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3-x}$$

Your expression can't be correct. Take for example $x = 1$

In general:

$$\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} =\sqrt\frac{a}{b} \neq \frac{a}{b}$$